# Since Feb. 6th, can I post to friends' timeline by Graph API call directly?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-timeline

My question is, 
if I am the user using an authorized web application, can I post something to my friends' timeline at once, and without any interactions with me?

I've read [this topic](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/) and other relative posts on stackoverflow, and I understand that facebook had made some changes.
But when I read Feed Dialog document, I find out that it said:

> Your application can also publish directly to a profile's timeline without interaction on the part of someone using your app. To accomplish this, use the corresponding [Graph API call](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/#graphapicall)

while "Graph API call" is an unavailable link. And I can't figure out what the corresponding graph api call is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot Post to User's Friends timelines through the Graph API, as simple as that. You can **only** Post to the authorized User's wall through the Graph API.

The only way to achieve the similar functionality, as the [blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/) that you have checked suggests is,

> If you want to allow people to post to their friend’s timeline from your app, you can invoke the feed dialog. Stories that include friends via user mentions tagging or action tagging will show up on the friend’s timeline (assuming the friend approves the tag).

Comment: how can i identify who are authorized users with the help of Graph api?