# How to post on friend wall from the user using Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My Facebook App using Graph API posting a post to friend wall of the user. But the post on friend wall shows **"post from my app"**. I have to show **the user name** instead of my app name.

My Code is

```
    $Facebook = new FB();
    $result = $Facebook->api('/1033301390979876/feed', 'POST', array(
        'access_token' => $access_token,
        'message' => 'Hey I m Using Ylla... Will U???',
        // 'from' => array('name' => 'Pandi Selvam' , 'id' => '1033371111983124' ),
        //'to' => array('name' => 'Mahesh Ramasamy' , 'id' => '1033301390979876' )

    ));
```

Here the to and from parameter is not working. I can post without to and from parameter.

Comment: The ability to post on Feed of User's friend has been depreciated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16604090/since-feb-6th-can-i-post-to-friends-timeline-by-graph-api-call-directly/16604959#16604959.

Comment: Is there any way to show the user name on post?

Comment: Nopes, even the feature to this from API has been depreciated. Are you still able to Post on Feed of User's Friend?

Comment: Nope. I can post if the user's friend also give permission to my app.

Comment: Can i send status message to user's friend about my app? ist possible?

Comment: may i ask why you would do that? what would be in that status message and why would the users friend be interested in that message? and no, it is not possible. at least not in the background, see my answer.

Comment: Instead of sending a Post you might think to use [Notifications API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/notifications/). But in the end you will just have to see what you want to share and use the API you think is best for your use case.

Comment: you can only use notifications on app users (luckily). please do not create spam apps ;)

Comment: I created the app for users to invite their friends to use my site.

Comment: with site you mean external website? that´s what like/send buttons are for ;)

Comment: Ya. That is external site. Im looking for Invite button through fb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to post to a friends wall with the Facebook API is with a FB.ui dialog, using the [JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/):

You can use the parameter "to", to add the ID of the friend. Of course this cannot be done in the background, the user has to authorize each post. Which is good, because posting on the friends wall is considered spam in most cases, that´s why it is not allowed that easily anymore.

Good thing about the FB.ui dialog: You are not allowed to prefill the message parameter (anymore), which has to be 100% user generated anyway while using the PHP SDK.

Edit: The "to" parameter does not exist anymore, and the new [Share-Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) replaces the Feed-Dialog.